# gl_PointSize performance in WebGL

Tags: webgl

I was playing around with WebGL when I noticed a surprising behavior. I used a uniform to change the variable `gl_PointSize` in the vertex shader and it seems that the larger `gl_PointSize` gets, the lower the performance is. I then found the [these benchmark results](https://gist.github.com/redhog/ad13fecff02c47a7d286) which collaborate my experiences.

Has anyone an explanation and a possible workaround / solution for this?

Comment: Since the graphic card has to draw more fragments this is not surprising.

Comment: The number of fragments generated grows quadratically with the point size.

Comment: @BDL,derhass This makes perfect sense - now my question is why I didn't think of this, but I'll have to answer this myself... ;-)